# how to create .tar file on windows OS?

Tags: tar

I am using `window OS`. I have a `folder` named as `myFolder` which contains many `files`, I need to convert that `myFolder` to `myFolder.tar` file. Anyone please suggest how to do it?

Comment: tar cvf <TarFileName.tar> <FolderName>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd get some form of tool (like 7zip) to do this - Google has alternatives and demos. Otherwise you'll need to do something like scp it to a linux server and tar it up via command line.

Comment: thanks I have done it using 7zip :)

Answer (score 4):

If Python is installed, then you can use the `tarfile` module:

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open('myFolder.tar', 'w') as tar:
    tar.add('myFolder/')
```

or if you want a compressed file, then do:

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open('myFolder.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as tar:
    tar.add('myFolder/')
```

## Links

- https://www.scribd.com/doc/521235/Python-Tutorial-tarfile-module
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#examples

Comment: thanks for your answar :)

Answer (score 2):

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ has ported the majority of Unix tools to the Win32 API, including `tar`.

Comment: thanks for your answar, but i can accept only one... i have done it using 7zip. by the way you have provide the valuable tools :)

Comment: `tar` has been included in Windows in 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows